# Can I adjust the "100+ matches in X files" from Intellijs "find in path"

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to change the max value of shown results in the "find in path" feature in intellij?
[image]

I sometimes wished that I would see more results. of course I would need to scroll much more, but that's what I want. Can I change that number 100 to like 200, 1000 or even maybe endless?

Comment: Intellij/pycharm are generally excellent tools, but this limit to 100 is absolutely ***terrible***.  I have called high level folks to deal with "bugs" in our/their code due to simply not seeing results.  But the solution is to go to `Registry` and change `ide.usages.page.size` (shown below)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Edit:** *This answer is outdated.* You can now set the parameter `ide.usages.page.size` to increase the number of displayed findings. See RoryGS' answer for details.

**Old answer:**

Currently you only have the option to hit the **Open in Find Window** button (in the bottom right). But there is an open issue for IntelliJ to change this limit: <s>https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-16377</s> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157855

[image: Find window]

Comment: You've linked the closed issue. The related open issue is here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157855.

Comment: I'm sorry. Had both open and copied the wrong address. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. So I need to wait, alright :)     I am very new to Intellij, and I am not really able to find the mentioned "Open in Find Window" ... (I changed several key bindings, but could you tell how I can find this window?)

Comment: Thanks for explaining that button :)

Comment: `ide.usages.page.size` is now also outdated

Comment: And https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157855seems to be resolved for a while now. Thx for the hint.

Answer (score 152):

Update: **2023-04-18** (image added), previously **2021-05-06**

Thanks to "**Dmitry Jemerov**" from **JetBrains/IntelliJ** for a update on this old topic.

Dmitry says:

"In **2021.2+** the limit is configurable in

1. **Settings**
2. **Advanced Settings**
3. **Maximum number of results to show in Find In Path/Show Usages preview**
   "

Point 3) above last I checked was under the headeding "**Find/Replace**"

**IntelliJ Settings Screenshot**
[image]

If you don't see the above and your version is older then the below might still apply.

---

Update: **2018-08-20**

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157855

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206164739--More-than-100-matches-in-search

Thanks to "**Andrey Dernov**" from **JetBrains/IntelliJ** for answer.

**Andrey said**:

> You can set **ide.usages.page.size** - IntelliJ Registry option. (**Help** | **Find Action**... type **Registry** and set the value in dialog):

This has helped me a lot for large project refactoring.

**IntelliJ Idea Registry Screenshot**
[image]

**IntelliJ Idea Find in Path Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: Any idea how much to worry about that "can significantly increase memory usage"? (how much memory can be eaten by grep GUI? maybe I should switch to `grep` or `rg` rather than fighting with IDE?)

Comment: A good point.
I presume the memory usage would depend on some factors like the size of your code base you are searching over (presuming there are a lot of smart indexes from the IDE devs), the number of results returned from your search, maybe the size of the files related to your results, the result to no of files (100 results to 1 file or 100 results to 100 files), and the size you set the max limit too. etc.
On modern devices with all the mem we have to spare, NVMe's, etc etc Its probably not a issue for most (I am lucky enough to have 32 GB).
That said: Who doesn't love Grep.

Comment: Outdated answer. Refer to Lukas's answer below.

Comment: The updated version of the answer "2021-05-06" referred to the same solution as posted by "Lukas Liesis". That said it didn't have a image for easy "reading". I have now taken a screenshot which should assist in readability and labeled the update "2023-04-18".
I have also spaced "Dmitry Jemerov" text for further readability.

Answer (score 7):

**This is correct way to do this**

Forget about all xml file edits/vm options in other answers. Open settings, go to "Advanced Settings" and set number to whatever you wish.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that you want to see more than 100 matches in the preview so that you can easily skim through the search results, including the context of the lines before and after each occurrence. You can get the same effect, with more than 100 matches, by turning on the **Preview Occurrences** mode after finding all results by clicking **Open in Find Window**.

[image: Preview Occurrentces setting in WebStorm]

Comment: THANK YOU! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

For JetBrain's IDEs in 2021,

1. Help > Edit Custom VM Options
2. add `-Dide.usages.page.size=200` for 200 results.

Adjust as desired. Restart the IDE for changes to take effect.

Add/adjust more VM options you like as well, like max memory usage for example.

[image: JetBrains 2021]

Answer (score -1):

For anyone wanting to update it outside of the IDE this registry property lives in the file:

```
YourInstall/options/ide.general.xml
```

and looks like this:

```
<application>
  ...
  <component name="Registry">
    <entry key="ide.usages.page.size" value="1001" />
    ...
  </component>
  ...
</application>
```

(
To clarify, since someone downvoted ... :-D

Doing it outside of the IDE, allows you to create an automatic script that updates this value for all developers on a team or in a company...
)