# Find more than 100 results in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I noticed that Android Studio 3.0.1 doesn't show more than 100 results in "Find in Path". I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803519/can-i-adjust-the-100-matches-in-x-files-from-intellijs-find-in-path) and [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000616530-Is-Find-in-Path-Broken-), both of which mention changing the value associated with `ide.usages.page.size` registry option, but I don't see such an option in the registry of my installation. Any idea what's going on or how I can change that number?

Comment: Check this doc https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config

Answer (score 18):

I am using **3.1.4**, just go to **Help** -> **Find Action** -> and then search **Registry** -> and after that go for **ide.usages.page.size** and set it's value to 1000(or whatever bigger value you want) and it will work just perfectly fine.

I found this solution here [Can I adjust the "100+ matches in X files" from Intellijs "find in path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803519/can-i-adjust-the-100-matches-in-x-files-from-intellijs-find-in-path)

Comment: This is basically the correct answer. However they should add an option to view more or see all when you really need to find something.

Comment: In `2021.3.1 Patch 1` it appears to be missing and https://stackoverflow.com/a/51242384/4130619 has answer

Answer (score 4):

"In 2021.2 the limit is configurable in Settings | Advanced Settings | Maximum number of results to show in Find In Path/Show Usages preview"

info from Dmitry Jemerov from JetBrains/IntelliJ via https://stackoverflow.com/a/51242384/4130619